# PageMethod reload page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

Hello I call static PageMethod from JS.
PageMethod send some information to emails.
When I call it, page reloads. 
How should i prevent reloading page during PageMethod and do it at ajax style?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the page from posting back you probably want to add `return false;` to the end of your javascript call.

Like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Call Page Methods"  
      OnClientClick="return fun()"/>
```

Then in JS:

```
function fun()
{     
      PageMethods.MyPageMethod(onSucceed, onError);
      return false;
}   
function onSucceed(result)
{
      alert(result);        
}
function onError(result)
{      
}
```